# A little assistance with my GUI programming integrated with recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion, applet, awt

Please I need some help with my GUI program in Java. My program uses GUI interface to take in the nth term from the user; it then calculates the Fibonacci number of that term and prints it in the interface. Please have a look at my program. I would like to know two things:

1. How do I assign a variable to the return value in the *fib* function?
2. After setting a variable to the return value, I want to have an access to that variable in my `actionPerformed` method, so I can print it to the interface.

#### Program

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUIwithRecursion extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
public static TextField numberTF = new TextField ();
public static TextField fibTF    = new TextField();

int result = fib(numberN);

public void init()
{
setBackground(Color.magenta);
Label     numberLB = new Label("n= ");
Button    calcBN   = new Button("Calculate");
Label     fibLB    = new Label("fib(n)= ");

setLayout(null);
numberLB.setBounds(10, 30, 100, 20);
numberTF.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);
numberTF.setBackground(Color.yellow);
fibLB.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 20);
fibTF.setBounds(10, 90, 100, 20);
fibTF.setBackground(Color.red);
calcBN.setBounds(10, 110, 100, 20);

add(numberLB);
add(numberTF);
add(fibLB);
add(fibTF);
add(calcBN);

calcBN.addActionListener(this);
}

public static int fib(int numberN)
{
    if (numberN<=1)
    {return 1;}
    
    else
    {return fib(numberN-1)+fib(numberN-2);}
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    int result = fib(numberN);
    fibTF.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How do I assign a variable to the return value in the fib function?

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());
int result = fib(number);
```

> 2) After setting a variable to the return value, I want to have an access to that variable in my actionPerformed function, so I can print it to the interface.

A better solution would be to perform the calculation in the `actionPerformed` method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());
    int result = fib(number);
    fibTF.setText(Integer.toString(result));
}
```

The next question would be, why `Applet` and why the AWT library?  Both have been superseded by Swing (and now JavaFX) and applets are now been actively blocked by most browsers.

You will generally get better support for Swing and JavaFX and most people are using those libraries for development of pure AWT now days

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for your help. Do you have any idea that if I set the return value to ta variable, Eclipse is giving me an error saying "unreachable code."?

Comment: I assume you mean you've tried putting another `return` statement in your  `fib` method?  If so, then it will never be executed, because you have a `if-else` statement which guarantees that something will be returned before it.

Comment: Oh okay. I changed it now, but I am getting errors when I started running the code. Please help.

Comment: Remove the line `int numberN = Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());`

Comment: Nope, `int numberN = Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());` is still there.  You need to get rid of it, because when it's instantiated, `numberTF` is empty, it has no text

Comment: If I remove the line 10 which is *int numberN = Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText());* it gives me an error in line 11 saying that numberN cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: `int result = fib(numberN);` should be `int result = fib(Integer.parseInt(numberTF.getText()));`, as I said in the original answer.  You need to get the "current"/"actual" value of the text field at the current point in time and not rely on some value you might have gotten some time ago, which is probably no longer valid.  This is the nature of event driven programming